# GWT CELLTABLE SimplePager : Event handling on first,last,next,prev button present in SimplePager?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

How to handle event on SimplePager? Event handling on first,last,next,prev button present in SimplePager?
I am using CellTable gwt 2.3.0

Right now I am parsing xml in which 100 records are present. xml coming from server.

@ time I am showing 100 reocrd per table_page i.e pageSize(100);

Whenever I will click next button then I will made server request for getting  next 1OO records
same way for every button..

How to Handle event on SimplePager ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

in fact, you don't need to handle event on pager, this is your data provider which takes care of loading.

Read the javadoc on simple pager : 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.html

the simple pager add buttons and call the data provider. It gives to the data provider all informations you need to load good records (offset, size...)

**EDIT:** create a new subclass of `AbstractDataProvider` ([javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html?overview-summary.html)) which implements the method `onRangeChanged`. In that method you get a `HasData` object which contains all information you need to call an rpc service (offset of visible items).

When you have received response of your service, call the `updateRowCount` and `updateRowData` method. This will update the display and the pager.

You don't need to register handler for pager buttons, only defines DataProvider and all will run like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to make server call on buttons(onclickHandler) present in SimplerPager widget

Comment: Jerome C. How to check/identify "user clicks on last button" in onRangeChanged method of AsyncDataProvider with the help of HasData<Record> display